# Is it worth reminding people to consider upvoting questions that they've answered?

Tags: discussion

Occasionally, I see a question where someone has posted a reasonable answer.  I still see the question with 0 votes.  Some of our community may be new to answering and participating on SE.  Should we post a comment suggesting they consider upvoting the question?  Or just upvote it ourselves and let it be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would prefer you didn't. I know folks mean well trying to help users who may not know better, but with so many users and so many posts vying for attention, that sort of prodding becomes noisy pretty fast.

The system already has prompts in place to remind people what is needed — a gentle nudge to do the right thing — but when folks start asking for up-votes and reminding users to accept their answers, it can become a bit annoying to everyone else looking on. And when those activities become the norm, [it can even become a bit harassing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate).